# Java - How to pass an object as a parameter to different classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Person {
   String name;

   public Person(String name){
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Index index = new Index();
        Person person = new Person("Paul");
        index.addPerson(person);
    }
}

public class Index{
    public void addPerson(Person person){
        System.out.println(person.toString());
        System.out.print(" - " + person.getName());
    }
}
```

Prints:
"[ProjectPath]Person@1431340 - null"

Why doesn't it print "Paul" and how to fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: The duplicate but also you forgot to initialize your field.

Comment: Where did I forgot to initialize exactly?

Comment: Your `Person`'s `name` field.

Comment: You should initialize it at your `Person` constructor

Comment: You need to set `this.name` in the constructor. If you had made the field `final` (good practice if you are not going to change it), the compiler would have told you about it.